# Vlookup only cells in output range when interior color is blue

Tags: excel, vba, cell, vlookup

I have a code where column "J" on the output sheet makes a vlookup in the pivot table on the source sheet.
The vlookup is done on whole column "J". However in column "J" there are different colored cells like blue and grey.

[image]

I would like to adjust the code to only do the vlookup on the blue colored cells.

I searched here on stack and the net on how to do that. The only usefull thing I could find was :

```
For Each cell In Selection
   If cell.Interior.Color = vbBlue Then
```

I tried to implement the above in the code below but I couldn't make it work unfortunately. Maybe someone here can help or has a better idea...

```
Sub VlookWhenBlue()
Dim SourceLastRow As Long, OutputLastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim outputBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, outputSheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'location of source and output workbook
    Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...xlsm")
    Set outputBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\....xls")
    
    'names of the worksheets
    Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("VAS pivot")
    Set outputSheet = outputBook.Worksheets("Invoice")

'last row of source
SourceLastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'last row in col
OutputLastRow = outputSheet.Cells(outputSheet.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

'apply formula
For i = 2 To OutputLastRow

    outputSheet.Range("J" & i).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D" & i & ",'[" & sourceBook.Name & "]" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$B$5:$E$" & SourceLastRow & ",3,0),0)"
    
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Edit: this is the updated none working version:

```
Sub VlookWhenBlue()
Dim SourceLastRow As Long, OutputLastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim outputBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, outputSheet As Worksheet



Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'location of source and output workbook
    Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...xlsm")
    Set outputBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...xls")
    
    
    'names of the worksheets
    Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("VAS pivot")
    Set outputSheet = outputBook.Worksheets("Invoice")

'last row of source
SourceLastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'last row in col
OutputLastRow = outputSheet.Cells(outputSheet.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

'apply formula

Dim cell As Range


For Each cell In outputSheet.Range("J4:J" & OutputLastRow).Cells

If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15773696 Then

    outputSheet.Range("J" & i).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D" & i & ",'[" & sourceBook.Name & "]" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$B$5:$E$" & SourceLastRow & ",3,0),0)"
    
    Else
    'do nothing
End If
Next


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see a check for the interior color within your sub. Please read [It's not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: Hi Ike, I deleted the part that didn't work because I've lost the overview on the working part due of it. But i added it now.

Comment: If the formatting is direct, I suggest you use the `Range.Find` function with the `searchformat` argument. See [Excel VBA Find - A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/). If you are using Conditional formatting, you will need to create a collection of the relevant cells first.

Comment: Check first which color you're dealing with, I highly doubt it's actually `vbBlue`. Check with `Debug.Print Range("B2").Interior.Color` or `?Range("B2").Interior.Color``in the immediate window. Then compare with that number instead. If you want to know which value vbBlue has, set one cell with VBA and then check it's interior color value again (should be 16711680).

Comment: Ron, thank you for the guide this looks usefull, let me try to understand this

Comment: Hi Notus Panda I checked it and it should be: 15773696

Comment: hello Ron, Notus Panda, I've tried to work with your advice however the code still doesn't work. Can you check what I'm missing? (I've pasted the latest version above)

Comment: Is the Color being set directly or by Conditional Formatting?

Comment: hi Ron, it's being set directly

Comment: @Tom I don't see where you are using the `Range.Find` method I recommended, and you are trying to do something with `VLOOKUP` which will only work on a contiguous range.

Comment: Hi Ron, I used the guide you recommended but this was the best I could get out of it...

Comment: @Tom I have posted an answer which show a simplified way using what I've recommended. I suggest you master and understand that, as the rest of your code is irrelevant to the problem you stated. After you have the color dependent vlookup working to your satisfaction, then you can begin to modify it to handle the rest of the problems implied in your existing code, but if that becomes a problem, that is a different problem from performing a color-dependent vlookup, and warrants a different question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I would approach this, depending on the exact situation.

If you are writing a UDF which is being called from a worksheet cell, then you'll need to loop through the cells.

The following returns a value if there is an exact match (eg `range_lookup=False` in the `VLOOKUP` function.

```
Function colVlookup(lookupValue, tableArray, colNum)
    Const clr As Long = 15773696
    Dim C As Range
    Dim res
    
For Each C In tableArray
    If Not IsEmpty(res) Then Exit For
    If C.Interior.color = clr And C.value = lookupValue Then _
        res = C.Offset(columnoffset:=colNum - 1).value
Next C
    
If Not IsEmpty(res) Then
    colVlookup = res
Else
    colVlookup = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End If

End Function
```

You would enter this in some worksheet cell as:

```
=colVlookup("genus",Input,2)
```

---

If you are writing a macro (Sub) procedure which will write the results to an output range, then you can use the `Range.Find` method.

The following function must be called from, and return the result to and `Sub`. That `Sub` can then write the results to the worksheet wherever you wish

```
Option Explicit
Sub cvl()
    Dim x
x = colorVlookup("genus", [Input], 2)
With Range("Output")
    .Clear
    .value = x
End With
End Sub
'--------------------------------
Function colorVlookup(lookupValue, tableArray As Range, colNum As Long)
    Const clr As Long = 15773696
    Dim C As Range
    
With Application.FindFormat
    .Clear
    .Interior.color = clr
End With

With tableArray.Columns(1)
    Set C = .Find(what:=lookupValue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=True)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        colorVlookup = C.Offset(columnoffset:=colNum - 1).value
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If
End With

End Function
```

As written, the above routines will return the **First** match, but you could modify them to return the last match, or even an array of all the matches.

They also look for an exact match, but could be modified to look for partial matches.

Note in the screenshot below that the routine is returning the second match of `genus` since the first instance is NOT blue.

[image]